# How can I encrypt my app's sandbox on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools

I need to encrypt my app's sandbox so even if they root the device they can't see my files. Is that something one can do on Android? If so, how?

And if it's not possible, what is the best practices way to encrypt/decrypt individual files in Kotlin on Android?

Comment: You've tagged [android-ndk], but you mention Kotlin.  Are you asking how to do this using native code in the NDK, or via Kotlin using the framework APIs?

Comment: Also it's worth noting that a modified device in the hands of a skilled reverse engineer could theoretically break most encryption methods, so it's a cat-and-mouse game with a sufficiently determined and skilled attacker...but you can certainly at least make it a lot more _difficult_ to read your files on a rooted device by using encryption.

Comment: We have C++ code as well, so a C++ solution would work. Ideally though, I'd hoped to find a way to just have Android do it and I don't need to write any code.